# I created log table for get transaction of main table but when i insert in main table, in log table id is NULL

Tags: c#, oracle

First I created `Main` table, after that for taking transaction of insert, update, delete transaction of one record, I create the `Log` table. Note that I use auto-increment in the `Main` table.

Table Structure of Main Table

[image: 1..Table Structure of Main Table]

Data of Main Table

[image: 2..Data of Main Table]

Table Structure of Log Table

[image: 3..Table Structure of Log Table]

Data of Log Table - Transaction

[image: 4..Data of Log Table - Transaction]

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE departments 
(
    ID           NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(50)  NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE departments ADD (
  CONSTRAINT dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID));

CREATE SEQUENCE dept_seq START WITH 1;
```

Trigger definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_bir 
BEFORE INSERT ON departments 
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT dept_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;`enter code here
/
```

My issue is: if I insert one row but in Log table id's value is NULL.

My stored procedure in Oracle for insert and update of the `Main` & `Log` tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SAVE_YARDMASTER_DATA(
    IP_YARD_NAME     IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_MATERIAL_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_MATERIAL_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_CAPACITY      IN VARCHAR2,
    -- IP_RID OUT NUMBER ,
    IP_IS_DELETE    IN NUMBER ,
    IP_LAST_UPD_UID IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_OPERATION    IN VARCHAR2,
    updaterowid     IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
    OUT_RETURN_MSG OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_RETURN_CODE OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := '';
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;
  IF IP_OPERATION  = 'INSERT' THEN
    INSERT
    INTO MST_VP_YARD
      (
        YARD_NAME,
        MATERIAL_TYPE,
        MATERIAL_NAME,
        CAPACITY,
        IS_DELETE,
        LAST_UPD_IS,
        LAST_UPD_UID
      )
      VALUES
      (
        IP_YARD_NAME ,
        IP_MATERIAL_TYPE ,
        IP_MATERIAL_NAME ,
        IP_CAPACITY ,
        IP_IS_DELETE ,
        SYSDATE ,
        IP_LAST_UPD_UID
      );
              INSERT
        INTO MST_VP_YARD_LOG
          (
            YARD_NAME,
            MATERIAL_TYPE,
            MATERIAL_NAME,
            CAPACITY,
           IS_DELETE,
            LAST_UPD_IS,
            LAST_UPD_UID

          )
          VALUES
          (

            IP_YARD_NAME ,
            IP_MATERIAL_TYPE ,
            IP_MATERIAL_NAME ,
            IP_CAPACITY ,
            IP_IS_DELETE ,
            SYSDATE ,
            IP_LAST_UPD_UID

          );
  END IF;
  IF IP_OPERATION = 'UPDATE' THEN
    UPDATE MST_VP_YARD
    SET YARD_NAME   = IP_YARD_NAME,
      MATERIAL_TYPE = IP_MATERIAL_TYPE,
      MATERIAL_NAME = IP_MATERIAL_NAME,
      CAPACITY      = IP_CAPACITY,
      IS_DELETE     = IP_IS_DELETE,
      LAST_UPD_IS   = SYSDATE,
      LAST_UPD_UID  = IP_LAST_UPD_UID
    WHERE RID       = updaterowid;
    INSERT
    INTO MST_VP_YARD_LOG
      (
        RID,
        YARD_NAME,
        MATERIAL_TYPE,
        MATERIAL_NAME,
        CAPACITY,
        IS_DELETE,
        LAST_UPD_IS,
        LAST_UPD_UID
      )
      VALUES
      (
        updaterowid,
        IP_YARD_NAME ,
        IP_MATERIAL_TYPE ,
        IP_MATERIAL_NAME ,
        IP_CAPACITY ,
        IP_IS_DELETE ,
        SYSDATE ,
        IP_LAST_UPD_UID
      );
  END IF;
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := 'SUCCESS';
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := SQLERRM;
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;
END P_SAVE_YARDMASTER_DATA;
```

Comment: What do you mean by Log tables ID value is NULL? How are you logging? More code and details will help us help you.

Comment: A missing `commit`? Also, what has your code got to do with the table structures you posted?

Comment: With your current code you are assigning the new id to the Newly Inserted rows Id field (this is from the main table). Have you tried putting the new Id in to a variable and then using that later on to give the Log table its own unique Id?

Comment: In Image i posted as - 4..Data of Log Table - Transaction, u can see ID is null.  @ArijitKanrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the `id` of the departments table using `returning` [syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause). 
And then use that id when inserting into `log` table.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SAVE_YARDMASTER_DATA(
    IP_YARD_NAME     IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_MATERIAL_TYPE IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_MATERIAL_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_CAPACITY      IN VARCHAR2,
    -- IP_RID OUT NUMBER ,
    IP_IS_DELETE    IN NUMBER ,
    IP_LAST_UPD_UID IN VARCHAR2,
    IP_OPERATION    IN VARCHAR2,
    updaterowid     IN VARCHAR2 := NULL,
    OUT_RETURN_MSG OUT VARCHAR2,
    OUT_RETURN_CODE OUT NUMBER)
IS
    my_id number;
BEGIN
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := '';
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;
  IF IP_OPERATION  = 'INSERT' THEN
    INSERT
    INTO MST_VP_YARD
      (
        YARD_NAME,
        MATERIAL_TYPE,
        MATERIAL_NAME,
        CAPACITY,
        IS_DELETE,
        LAST_UPD_IS,
        LAST_UPD_UID
      )
      VALUES
      (
        IP_YARD_NAME ,
        IP_MATERIAL_TYPE ,
        IP_MATERIAL_NAME ,
        IP_CAPACITY ,
        IP_IS_DELETE ,
        SYSDATE ,
        IP_LAST_UPD_UID
      ) RETURNING id INTO my_id;
              INSERT
        INTO MST_VP_YARD_LOG
          (
            RID,  
            YARD_NAME,
            MATERIAL_TYPE,
            MATERIAL_NAME,
            CAPACITY,
            IS_DELETE,
            LAST_UPD_IS,
            LAST_UPD_UID

          )
          VALUES
          (
            my_id,
            IP_YARD_NAME ,
            IP_MATERIAL_TYPE ,
            IP_MATERIAL_NAME ,
            IP_CAPACITY ,
            IP_IS_DELETE ,
            SYSDATE ,
            IP_LAST_UPD_UID

          );
  END IF;
  IF IP_OPERATION = 'UPDATE' THEN
    UPDATE MST_VP_YARD
    SET YARD_NAME   = IP_YARD_NAME,
      MATERIAL_TYPE = IP_MATERIAL_TYPE,
      MATERIAL_NAME = IP_MATERIAL_NAME,
      CAPACITY      = IP_CAPACITY,
      IS_DELETE     = IP_IS_DELETE,
      LAST_UPD_IS   = SYSDATE,
      LAST_UPD_UID  = IP_LAST_UPD_UID
    WHERE RID       = updaterowid;
    INSERT
    INTO MST_VP_YARD_LOG
      (
        RID,
        YARD_NAME,
        MATERIAL_TYPE,
        MATERIAL_NAME,
        CAPACITY,
        IS_DELETE,
        LAST_UPD_IS,
        LAST_UPD_UID
      )
      VALUES
      (
        updaterowid,
        IP_YARD_NAME ,
        IP_MATERIAL_TYPE ,
        IP_MATERIAL_NAME ,
        IP_CAPACITY ,
        IP_IS_DELETE ,
        SYSDATE ,
        IP_LAST_UPD_UID
      );
  END IF;
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := 'SUCCESS';
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  OUT_RETURN_MSG  := SQLERRM;
  OUT_RETURN_CODE := 0;
END P_SAVE_YARDMASTER_DATA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the ID using a trigger. So you can use the `RETURNING INTO` statement to get the ID that was generated into a variable. Use that ID to now insert into the log table. 
Check this out

[Oracle DML Returning Into Clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause)

Comment: Thank you so much @Plirkee... Successfully Worked.

Comment: Thank you so much @Arijit Kanrar... Your reply Help me.